# Mocking new instance creation inside testing class using mockito

Tags: java, initialization, mockito, spy

I am attempting to mock the new instance of an object inside the class I'm testing but I'm struggling to find a way to do this using Mockito.

If I understand this correctly, this might be something that can be achieved using Powermock but I only have Mockito at my disposal I can use.

Here's what I'm trying to do

```
   private class MyTestClass{
      private doSomethingMethod(){
        Object obj = new Object();
        obj.getSomething;
      }
   }
```

I am currently spying on MyTest class and would like to mock the new Object so that I can manipulate the result of obj.getSomething()

Is this something achievable using Mockito?
Thank you

Comment: Unfortunately, Powermock(ito) is one answer. Mockito doesn't intercept object instantiation :( ** Edit - unless you move the object instantiation to a new package-visible method and then mock the response to that method in your spy. But then your code is written at the whim of your tests.

Comment: Without PowerMock you will need to refactor your code to make the instance available for mocking, for example, moving your object creation to a factory or a provider method, and then mock the method/factory return accodingly

Comment: Check [this](https://code.google.com/archive/p/mockito/wikis/MockingObjectCreation.wiki) out. But, as pointed out in the earlier comments, refactoring is required for sure. (though it is easy in PowerMock)

Comment: Thank you guys, that's what I was afraid of, sadly refactoring is limited as this is legacy code and I'm trying to achieve some test coverage with minimal refactoring. Powermock seems like the only option. I'm just wondering, so far I'm using mockito, if I add powermock, will it start conflicting with my mockito tests?

Comment: @Sgr No it won't. We use Powermock along with Mockito and there are no conflicts.

Comment: Hi Aditya, I have made use of the link you've provided and it's useful, it can be used to mock new instances with mimimal refactoring. I know it's not ideal but the best solution when you can't use Powermock. I've noticed that static methods are being used in my test class as well and they are not supported by mockito, any refactoring solution that can allow me to mock values from static methods?thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMHO everything is better in your case than using Powermock, as you already stated.

In similar cases I am using a solution which puts the "unmockable" code in an as-small-as-possible method and `@Spy` around like:

```
public class SpyTest {
    @Spy
    private MyTestClass myTestClass;

    @Before
    public void initMocks() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void spyInsteadOfPowermock() {
        when(myTestClass.getObject()).thenReturn(Integer.valueOf(3));

        assertThat(myTestClass.doSomethingMethod()).isEqualTo("3");
    }

    class MyTestClass{
        public String doSomethingMethod(){
            return getObject().toString();
        }

        Object getObject() {
            return new Object();
        }
    }
}
```