# Mocking of a class method is not working in java

Tags: java, junit, mockito

Attached the code and it's test below :

```
public class A {
    private B b;

    public A(C c) {
        b = new B(c);
    }

    public ResponseOutput method1(RequestInput request) {
        ResponseOutput responseOutput = b.method2(param1, param2);
        //Do something based on responseOutput. e.g. throwException if some condition meet
        return responseOutput;
    }
}


public class ATest {

    @Mock
    private C c;
    @Mock
    private B b;
    @InjectMocks
    private A a;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void method1_test1() {
        ResponseOutput responseOutput = something;
        Mockito.when(b.method2(Mockito.any(), Mockito.any())).thenReturn(responseOutput);
        a.method1(param1, param2);
    }
}
```

b.method2 is not getting mocked. Call is going to it's internal functions. Is there any other annotation needed for mocking class B.

Comment: Don’t you usually have to annotate the test class with either the mockito runner or extension?

Answer (score 0):

First, @InjectMocks will create the mock object (creating a new object every time an @Test method is run)

However, you are not using that created instance - instead you are creating a new instance directly in your @Before method.  @InjectMocks has no effect on that created instance.

So you need to decide, do you want to use the @InjectMocks created instance of A, or do you you want to use your own (in which case, you must set b yourself - maybe using PowerMock to mock the new call, or alternatively use ideas from [Mocking new instance creation inside testing class using mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55329877/mocking-new-instance-creation-inside-testing-class-using-mockito) ).

In addition, @InjectMocks will still not set b for you, because Java initialises objects in order of declaration, which results in @InjectMocks only being able to inject @Mock variables declared before it -  so you would have to switch the ordering around to have @InjectMocks AFTER the @Mock declarations.

Comment: Changed the code to public class ATest {

    Mock
    private C c;

    Mock
    private B b;

    InjectMocks
    private A a;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
          MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }
} But still it is not getting mocked.

Comment: Updated the changes in the question

Comment: Strictly speaking, it IS being injected, but the constructor then executes `b = new B(c);`, so overwriting the mocked value.   So your options are Powermock, etc as mentioned in the answer - or alternatively, could you refactor your code so that A is given the B instead of having to create it itself ?

Comment: Not sure why and what change i did, but it is working fine now. I tried to replicate the previous code, but it is working there as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

`@InjectMock` will try to use the biggest constructor to create and inject the mocked dependencies into A .(Refer [this](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html) for detail of its behaviour) which in your case is :

```java
 A a = new A(c);
```

Now you manually create a B instance inside this constructor which causes B inside A is a real instance but not a mocked one. So what you stub on the mocked B does not have any effect because A is not calling it.

Actually , A only needs to directly interact with B and so you do not need to mock C . First refactor A such that it can be directly created using B only :

```java
public class A {
    private B b;

    public A(B b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

And then update the test to :

```java
public class ATest {
    @Mock
    private B b;

    @InjectMocks
    private A a;


    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void method1_test1() {
 
    }
 }
```

Please note that you have to remove the constructor `public A(C c)` from A. Otherwise , `@InjectMocks` will just randomly choose `public A(C c)` or `public A(B b)` to create A because both are the biggest constructors.

If you do not want to remove  constructor `public A(C c)` , don't use  `@InjectMocks` to create A but simply create it by yourself :

```java
public class ATest {
    @Mock
    private B b;


    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void method1_test1() {
        A a = new A(b);
        //do your test....
    }
 }
```